# Java get FirstDate and LastDate of following month in MM/dd/yyyy format even if the input is not the first day of the month

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar

I have a function below which has an input **Date** and it will return the first and last **Date** of the next month in `MM/dd/yyyy` format.

```java
String string = "01/01/2022";
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date dt = sdf .parse(string);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(dt);
c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);  
String firstDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
System.out.println("FirstDate:" + firstDate);
c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
String lastDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
System.out.println("LastDate:" + lastDate);
```

The above will give me an output like below

```
FirstDate:02/01/2022
LastDate:02/28/2022
```

This works well if the input is the first day of the previous month, what i would like to achieve is to get the FirstDate and LastDate of the next `month` even if the input is a date which is not the first date of the month for example `01/31/2022` gives me the output below

```
FirstDate:02/28/2022
LastDate:03/27/2022
```

But i would still like it to give me the first out of

```
FirstDate:02/01/2022
LastDate:02/28/2022
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar`. Those classes are notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use Date as it is obsolete and buggy.  Use [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) and other classes from the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

- the following takes an existing date first, adds `1` to the month. This will also cause the year to increase if required.
- then the `dayOfMonth` as either `1` or the last day of the month.  Leap years are automatically considered.

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("12/22/2020", dtf);
date = date.plusMonths(1);
LocalDate endDate = date.withDayOfMonth(date.lengthOfMonth());
LocalDate startDate = date.withDayOfMonth(1);
System.out.println("FirstDate: " +startDate.format(dtf));
System.out.println("LastDate:  " +endDate.format(dtf));
```

prints

```
FirstDate: 01/01/2021
LastDate:  01/31/2021
```

Answer (score 4):

You can have that easier in Java 8. Use a `java.time.YearMonth`, get the current one with its method `now()` and derive the first and last `LocalDate` of it:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // get the current month
    YearMonth currentMonth = YearMonth.now();
    // get the date with day of month = 1 using the current month
    LocalDate firstOfMonth = currentMonth.atDay(1);
    // then get its last date (no number required here)
    LocalDate lastOfMonth = currentMonth.atEndOfMonth();
    // prepare a formatter for your desired output (default: uuuu-MM-dd)
    DateTimeFormatter customDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu");
    // print the month and year without a formatter (just for visualization)
    System.out.println("Month:     " + currentMonth);
    // then print both desired dates using the custom formatter
    System.out.println("FirstDate: " + firstOfMonth.format(customDtf));
    System.out.println("LastDate:  " + lastOfMonth.format(customDtf));
}
```

This prints

```
Month:     2022-05
FirstDate: 05/01/2022
LastDate:  05/31/2022
```

You can – of course – use any given month, there is `YearMonth.of(int year, int month)` which you could use in order to create your example value:

```java
YearMonth currentMonth = YearMonth.of(2022, 2);
```

Comment: Where is the input for date date

Comment: Better to provide the first and last day of **next month** as question required.

Comment: You‘re right @samabcde, I will change that accordingly soon…

Comment: @EmmanuelNjorodongo sorry, just forgot the input… would basically lead to the accepted answer, so I will leave this for future readers who only read your question title…